# Random Number Generator not working with 2D arrays that output - C++

Tags: c++, random

Okay, so I have a problem. I am trying to get the code to output to the console in a format like this:

```
123456
789012
345678
901234
567890
123456
```

But it is displaying like this:

```
123456
```

I don't know what the problem is, but here is the code:

```
void mazeLayout() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int mazeLayoutArraySize = 6;
    int mazeLayoutOne = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwo = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThree = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutFour = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutFive = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutSix = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutSeven = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutEight = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutNine = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutEleven = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwelve = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirteen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutFourteen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutFifteen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutSixteen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutSeventeen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutEightteen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutNineteen = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwenty = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyOne = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyTwo = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyThree = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyFour = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyFive = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentySix = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentySeven = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyEight = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutTwentyNine = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirty = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirtyOne = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirtyTwo = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirtyThree = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirtyFour = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirtyFive = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutThirtySix = rand()%6+1;
    int mazeLayoutArray[mazeLayoutArraySize][mazeLayoutArraySize]={{mazeLayoutOne, mazeLayoutTwo, mazeLayoutThree, mazeLayoutFour, mazeLayoutFive, mazeLayoutSix},
                               {mazeLayoutSeven, mazeLayoutEight, mazeLayoutNine, mazeLayoutTen, mazeLayoutEleven, mazeLayoutTwelve},
                               {mazeLayoutThirteen, mazeLayoutFourteen, mazeLayoutFifteen, mazeLayoutSixteen, mazeLayoutSeventeen, mazeLayoutEightteen},
                               {mazeLayoutNineteen, mazeLayoutTwenty, mazeLayoutTwentyOne, mazeLayoutTwentyTwo, mazeLayoutTwentyThree, mazeLayoutTwentyFour},
                               {mazeLayoutTwentyFive, mazeLayoutTwentySix, mazeLayoutTwentySeven, mazeLayoutTwentyEight, mazeLayoutTwentyNine, mazeLayoutThirty},
                               {mazeLayoutThirtyOne, mazeLayoutThirtyTwo, mazeLayoutThirtyThree, mazeLayoutThirtyFour, mazeLayoutThirtyFive, mazeLayoutThirtySix}};

//for loop to read rows
for(int index1=0; index1<6; index1++){
        for(int index2=0; index2<6; index2++) {
            cout << mazeLayoutArray[index1][index2];
        }
        cout << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

}
```

```
If you have any questions, just ask me!
```

Comment: First question: why don't you use a loop to *fill* the array?

Comment: in C++ you should use the random number generators in the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header not `rand()` which is a notoriously bad random number generator.

Comment: Second question, why don't you try this first with a 2x2 array and hard-coded values?

Comment: Third question (and this is the cruncher): **why do you put `exit` *inside* the loop?**

Comment: I am amazed that somebody sat down and typed in those variable names - twice

Comment: Maybe the poster wrote a C++ application to generate all the variable names :)

Comment: @MattCoubrough - Is that better?

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer `mazeLayout36` rather than `mazeLayoutThirtySix`, at least. ;)

Comment: @T.C. -  Why not mazeLayout69 - That is my preference

Comment: Forget the loop. use `std::generate`.

Comment: I you like to put you out of your misery of typing in variable names

Comment: The asker is making too many mistakes to be ready for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int index1=0; index1<6; index1++){
    for(int index2=0; index2<6; index2++) {
        cout << mazeLayoutArray[index1][index2];
    }
    cout << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

After the inner loop prints out the first line, you just `exit()`'d the program.